# p:datatable selectAllRows api calls don't trigger rowSelect Event

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable, multipleselection

I have a `p:dataTable` with `selectionMode=multiple` which binds the `rowSelect` and `rowUnselect` event:

```
<p:dataTable 
    widgetVar="myDatatable" 
    selectionMode="multiple" 
    selection="#{myBean.selection}">
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.onSelect}" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{myBean.onUnselect}" />
... (columns)
</p:dataTable>
```

Selecting rows works fine, `myBean.selection` is updated and `myBean.onSelect()` is invoked.

Now I wanted to add buttons to (un)select all items to my Toolbar. I created two `<p:commandLink>`s:

```
<p:commandLink onclick="PF('myDatatable').selectAllRows();" 
            update="actionbarForm">select all</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink onclick="PF('myDatatable').unselectAllRows();" 
            update="actionbarForm">unselect all</p:commandLink>
```

The selection seems to work, I can see that either all items are (un)selected. However, neither `myBean.selection` nor `myBean.onSelect()` are updated/invoked. What do I have to do that to enable this?

Comment: I have no real idea, but what so I should go into debugging things to find out more, but out of curiosity, what did **you** debug? Ajax calls? Network traffic? Inspected the PrimeFaces source (both js and java files). Lots of things you can do

Comment: I checked, there's no Ajax-Call or network traffic when invoking `selectAllRows()`. I also tried invoking `PF('myDatatable').fireRowSelectEvent()` before or after calling `selectAllRows()`, but I couldn't figure out the correct params.

Comment: And if you use it with a 'commandButton' that e.g. fires a call from the page (after using the selectAllRows function). E.g. like in the showcase of 'Multiple with Meta and Shift keys'

Comment: Adding an action to the commandLink doesn't change anything. The example "Multiple with Meta and Shift keys" only shows the result of the selection, which works for me when selection items one by one.

Comment: I tried this latter IN the showcase by running `PF('widget_form_multipleDT').selectAllRows()` from the developer console and then pressing the 'view' button. It then seems to work that the server has all rows and displays them. Just no 'rowSelect' event

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I leave out the `<p:ajax>`-events the selection is updated correctly for my datatable. But I would need the events, so leaving them out is not an option, unfortunately...

Comment: I think I have a solution after investigating the source code (it is very readable). I'll post it here if you after that file an enhancement request with PF to have the 'toggleSelect' events fired on these two javascript calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two PrimeFaces javascript api calls do in no way interact with any of the ajax events. This can be seen in the datatable.js in [`selectAllRows()`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L1737) and [`unselectAllRows()`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L1689) If you do not use ajax but a normal 'submit' via a button, you'll see that PrimeFaces expands the selection to 'all' on the server side. For this it passes the `@all` value of the selection to the server.

You'll also see in the source that there already is some code to send a '[toggleSelect](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L1791)` ajax event, so I put it in a function extending the PrimeFaces datatable:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.fireToggleSelectEvent = function(checked) {
    //fire toggleSelect event
    if(this.cfg.behaviors) {
        var toggleSelectBehavior = this.cfg.behaviors['toggleSelect'];

        if(toggleSelectBehavior) {
            var ext = {
                    params: [{name: this.id + '_checked', value: checked}
                ]
            };

            toggleSelectBehavior.call(this, ext);
        }
    }
}
```

After calling the (un)selectAllRows() via the widget, you can call this function too, with either a true (select) or false (unselect) value as the parameter.

If you then add the toggleSelect ajax to your datatable

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{dtSelectionView.onToggleSelect}" update=":form:msgs" />
```

and in your bean add a handler:

```
public void onToggleSelect(ToggleSelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(event.isSelected() ? "All Selected" : "All Unselected");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

It all works. (PrimeFaces 6.0, code tested against showcase)

You could also override both the (un)selectAllRows in the PrimeFaces datatable.js and at the end call the fireToggleSelectEvent, so all is in one functioncall (or combine both separate calls in one custom function).