# Trigger AJAX on the Select All Check boxes Primefaces DataTable

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I need to execute a backing bean method when the user selects that checkbox on the top (the one that selects all the check-boxes).

I'm talking about this one:

[image]

As for the regular check boxes:

[image]

I was able to execute a backing bean method by adding the following tags inside the `<p:dataTable><p:dataTable/>`:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{beanJanela.atualizaVariacaoSaldo}" update="variacaoSaldo" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{beanJanela.atualizaVariacaoSaldo}" update="variacaoSaldo" />
```

It almost seems like it would be a matter of just adding another `<p:ajax .. />` with an event like `rowSelectAllCheckbox`, unfortunately that event does not exist.

So how would I go about executing `#{beanJanela.atualizaVariacaoSaldo}` when that first checkbox is selected? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934313/pdatatable-selectallrows-api-calls-dont-trigger-rowselect-event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Primefaces User Guide (Version 6.2), page 181 offers the following event on p:datatable:

**Event**: toggleSelect
**Listener Parameter**: org.primefaces.event.ToggleSelectEvent
**Fired**: When header checkbox is toggled.

So try using

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" .../>
```

on the datatable.

Comment: So effectively it is a 'RTFM' question... reading the fine manual ;-)